# JavaScript get start of current minute

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get the value (elapsed milliseconds) equivalent of the start of the current minute using JavaScript:

```
let now = Date.now().setSeconds(0);
```

That is leading to an error:

```
Date.now(...).setSeconds is not a function
```

The same error appears if I try""

```
let now = Date.now();
now.setSeconds(0);
```

What is the correct way to make it work? I expect to return, for example, `1543484520000` for `Thu Nov 29 2018 07:42:00 GMT-0200`

Comment: new Date().getSeconds()

Comment: Use `new` to create a Date object. Reading [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) is always useful.

Comment: You question is for `get` but you are `setting` seconds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what you want I think

```js
let now = new Date();
now.setSeconds(0);
console.log(now.getTime());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
let now = new Date();
now.setSeconds(0);
console.log(now.getMilliseconds());
console.log(now.getTime());
```

Once you have the date object, you can get out what you need. See documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: I expect to return a number containing the milliseconds, not a date object.

Comment: getMilliseconds() returns 0-999 milliseconds of the specified date and time. I don't think that is what OP is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

To get Seconds :-

```js
date = new Date();
milliseconds = date.getTime();
seconds = milliseconds / 1000;
console.log("milliseconds : "+milliseconds + " seconds : "+seconds );
```

To set seconds :-

```js
let date = new Date();
date.setSeconds(0);
milliseconds = date.getTime();
seconds = milliseconds / 1000;
console.log("milliseconds : "+milliseconds + " seconds : "+seconds );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the timestamp to remove the seconds.

```js
var timestamp = new Date(+new Date() - ((+new Date()) % 60000));
console.log(+timestamp);
```